# avoid memory fragmentation by load libraries anywhere we want

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system

In order to avoid avoid memory fragmentation, it is useful to load libraries anywhere we want. However, this is not always possible depending on how the library is compiled.

I have a multiple choice question that asks

```
What must we ensure the library adheres to?

A. calling conventions

B. position independent code

C. absolute addressing

D. ELF specification
```

Should I ensure the library adheres to position independent code? Can you explain why does this work? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some more context.